# Android update lib-project build file creates apk instead of jar

Tags: android, ant, build

I recently upgraded to Android SDK Tools Ref 20, Platform-tools rev 12, Android 4.1 (API 16).  When i execute "Android update lib-project" for my project, then use "ant debug" or "ant release", an apk file is created for the project.  The previous version created a jar file (which is what i wanted).  Did this break or is this new, expected behaviour.

Thanks -- Dan'l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is when you do android create lib-project, it adds `android.library=true` into the file `project.properties`

if you do then android update lib-project, for a strange reason the `android.library=true` is removed (see [Android issue 38270](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38270#c1))

solution:

move to android update project, and be sure you have the project.properties without delete it

Answer (score 1):

I might not have exact ans to your question but i can inform you that I tried building library project with ADT20 and output is `classes.jar`. So I dont see any issue. I tried on an existing project.

Are you creating a new library project and then trying it?

Comment: THanks.  It looks like the "android.library=true" was removed from my project.properties file.  I'm sure that was me and had nothing to do with the upgrade :)